# VBA Vlookup gives N/A, but regular Vlookup gives correct result

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code that when run is returning N/A, but if I do the normal Vlookup in the cells it returns the correct information.

```
=VLOOKUP(A6,'[AR Aging Detail Report as of 06-26-2017.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$V,5,FALSE)
```

That's the normal Vlookup that works in the cells. I have this code which only returns N/A for all cells. I can post the full code, but this is what is relevant. xlWS and xlWB2 are defined earlier as the relevant workbooks.

```
xlWS.Activate
With xlWS
    For i = 2 To rCount
        sFormula = Application.VLookup(Range("A" & i), xlWB2.Sheets(1).Range("H:V"), 5, False)
```

What could be wrong here? The vlookup looks to be the same.

Adding full code for context. It first finds the most recent file with "AR Aging*" as the name and assigns it to xlWB2. That's the bulk of the code there. Then I try to run the Vlookup on each row and put the returned value in column 'O' of xlWB.

```
 'Specify the path to the folder
MyPath = "C:\Users\TheAgency\Documents\test"

'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

'Get the first Excel file from the folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "AR Aging*.xlsx", vbNormal)

'If no files were found, exit the sub
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

    'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

    'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
    'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If

    'Get the next Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir

Loop

'Open the latest file
Set xlWB2 = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile, True, True)

On Error Resume Next
' test if excel is already running
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' Excel is not running
    ' so create an object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Else
    ' flag. excel is already running before we execute this code
    bolIsExcelRunning = True
End If

xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH & "hdremittance.csv")
Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets("hdremittance")
Set xlWS2 = xlWB2.Sheets(1)
xlSheetName = xlWS2.Name

rCount = xlWS.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1
Debug.Print "rCount : " & rCount

' rCount2: 6 Months Row Count
On Error Resume Next
rCount2 = xlWS2.Range("D:D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions).Count - 1
Debug.Print "rCount2 : " & rCount2

Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Sheet2"
Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "returns"
Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = ".com"
Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Shortage"
Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "No Store"

xlWS.Activate
With xlWS
    For i = 2 To rCount
        sFormula = Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), xlWB2.Sheets(1).Range("A:J"), 3, True)
        rFormula = Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), xlWB2.Sheets(1).Range("A:J"), 2, False)
        Inv = Application.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), xlWB2.Sheets(1).Range("A:V"), 6, False)
        Debug.Print sFormula
        .Range("O" & i).Value = sFormula
        .Range("R" & i).Value = rFormula
        .Range("S" & i).Value = "Wire Transfer"
        .Range("T" & i).Value = "1200"
        .Range("U" & i).Value = "4699"
        .Range("V" & i).Value = "1100"
        .Range("X" & i).Value = Inv
        DoEvents
    Next
End With
```

Comment: doesn't look like it should matter but try `.Range("A" & i)`.

Comment: How/where does it return "N/A" ?

Comment: You should show more code if possible, for context. `Application.Vlookup` *can't* strictly return an "N/A" but it can return an `Error 2042` which displays as "#N/A" on the worksheet.

Comment: I tried the .Range which didn't help.

It returns N/A later in the code when I write the value to a cell.
    .Range("O" & i).Value = sFormula

Comment: Step one: comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and see if you get errors.  Also , if you're running this code from excel, why do you have the GetObject/CreateObject code ?  There you just set xlApp to the already existing Application object...

Comment: That's another issue I was trying to get past. The count fails with "1004 - No cells were found", so I used the rCount in the loop instead of rCount2 for now. I was going to look at that later. I am very new, so this is Frankenstein code. I have copied code and altered it to my needs really. I guess I can remove that GetObject if it isn't needed.

Comment: If you use On Error Resume Next you should try to cancel it out as soon as possible, otherwise the rest of your code can fail without you knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your reference to Sheets(1) is not correct.  I rebuilt your procedure and found the Error 2042 (#N/A) is returned if there is no match.  Your formula clearly shows you are referring to "Sheet1" but your code indicates Sheets(1), which may not necessarily be the same thing.  Replace "Sheets(1)" with "Sheets("Sheet1")" and try again.

Comment: Still get the same thing. There is only 1 sheet on that workbook.

Comment: @Cody Harris, looking at your code it seems that the function should be returning the values you are anticipating unless the key value is not presenting the lookup range, at which point an #N/A is provided.  It may be best to review your workbooks and confirm that your formula is setup correctly to return the intended values.  It would also be wise to take Tim Williams advice and use the existing Application object to open the xlWB2 object and clean up your error management a bit as his point about resume next are very valid and potentially problematic.